# How to catch ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED thrown by browser if server goes down?

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I think this question is pretty straightforward, but I haven't found an answer yet in the official [Socket.io docs](http://socket.io/docs/).

I have my Socket.io server and client communicating successfully, and when I shut down the server, the client will attempt to reconnect with the server unsuccessfully. This is shown in the Chrome developer's console here:

[image]

Is there any way to detect this event in the client-side Javscript and react to it some way? I'm thinking I would display a dialog on the page, such as "Sorry, server is under heavy load", etc.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

The correct way to handle this, as of Socket 1.x, is to use the [Manager](http://socket.io/docs/client-api/#manager(url:string,-opts:object)) object for a given socket. It throws a `connect_error` event that can be handled as shown:

```
socket.io.on('connect_error', function(err) {
  // handle server error here
  console.log('Error connecting to server');
});
```

Comment: Many thanks, you saved the day, it's not documented well.

Answer (score 4):

This should work:

```
var socket = io('http://localhost');
socket.on('connect_error', function(err) {
  // notify user
});
```

Comment: A small correction: the valid form is `socket.io.on('connect_error', function() {...})`

Comment: For some reason, I couldn't get this to work. I see the errors popping up in the console, but the handler is never called.

Comment: All I'm trying to do is catch the error on the client side, if the server was down, for example. Any ideas?

Comment: @BigMario I'm not able to get it fixed. Can you explain how curious comment helped you ?

Answer (score 1):

As of now and in the past there is no way to "*handle*" the **red** messages. **You can't hide them.**

Reference:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/43056626/5563074

You can't **hide** them but socket.io **does have a way to catch** them like presented earlier.

```js
socket.on('connect_error', function(e){
   //Do something
   //console.log(e);
});
```

Docs:
https://socket.io/docs/client-api/#Event-%E2%80%98connect-error%E2%80%99