# Hosting Issue on Win 10 with NodeJS React App, IIS, Namecheap DNS

Tags: node.js, reactjs, iis, hosting

So i have a few issues with Hosting a node react app on my computer on my Computer.  I've completed the following steps, but I still seem to have a few problems.   Here are some steps i've taken

**Namecheap DNS**

- added A records @ and WWW under Advanced DNS, with my IP as Value, and TTL automatic

**Router**

- added a static IP for the computer hosting the Site
- added port forwarding for external port 80, internal port 3000 for the host computer

**IIS**

- enabled IIS in Windows
- added Application Request Routing
- added URL rewrite
- added binding Type http Port 3000 IP address * and pointed it to my projects build file
- process model identity updated to my login, pw

**URL Rewrite**

- added a reverse proxy rewrite rule http://localhost:3000/{R:1}

**HTTP Response Headers**

- X-Frame-Options value SAMEORIGIN
- Content-Security-Policy value default-src https: data: 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'
- add_header X-Xss-Protection value 1;  mode=block
- X-Content-Type-Options value nosniff

**Node/React Application**

- using github Basir/Amazona example with some small modifications for my needs.
- have installed all dependencies
- used npm build

**My Issues**

- When i use NPM start, I can see the website by typing my IP address into the browser.  However i can't see the page when i type in the mywebsite.com, i get ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED using a desktop and chrome.
- when start the website in IIS, the same issue persists, but the ip address doesn't show the website either.  Additionally a 404 error persists when pulling information from the backend server hosted on localhost:5000

I do use bitdefender, and would prefer not to take it down, as I've seen dozens of exploit attempts since setting this up.

If anyone has some suggestions, or would like to walk me through some steps to take, it would be appreciated.  I would like to get this up and running, sooner the better.

Comment: You can access the service through the IP address but not through the domain name, right? I think this may be a problem with the DNS server but it may also be related to chrome. I found a similar problem on SO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43012334/silence-neterr-connection-refused

Comment: I tried firefox, and i get invalid host header when i use the myaddress.com.  using my IP will again, bring up the app

Comment: This should be related to the DNS server, DNS should not successfully resolve the domain name into an IP address.

Comment: How should the DNS successfully resolve?  Where should I be pointing it?

Comment: For more information about "Best practices for DNS client settings", you can refer to this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/networking/best-practices-for-dns-client-settings