# socket.io client events are not firing

Tags: websocket, socket.io, sails.js

I am trying to run my client without my server connected (on purpose) and catch `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` error and display it to the user. I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24683572/how-to-catch-err-connection-refused-thrown-by-browser-if-server-goes-down) that this can be achieved using socket events, specifically `connect_error`

Below in my code, I can never get the events to fire and display the console logs inside. logging `this.io.socket` prints stuff but none of the events do.. why is that?

```
$.ajax(args)
        .done((msg) => {
          this.io.socket.on('connect', msg => {
            console.log('connect socket io', msg)
          })
          resolve(msg);
        })
        .fail((jqXHR, msg) => {
          return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            console.log('inside promise of fail() - this.io.socket', this.io.socket) // this will log data to console

            this.io.socket.on('connect_error', msg => {
              console.log('connect_error socket io', msg)
            })

            this.io.socket.on('connect_failed', (msg) => {
              console.log('connect_failed', msg);
            });

            // return some error here for user
          })
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I see, you are attempting to wire up the event handlers only if you get a bad response from your **first ajax** call. This will not result in any of the socket.io event handlers being initiated.

Move the event handler into the code where you initialize the socket instance.

See below for a full example where all the `manager` and `socket` events will be logged to console.

```
$.ajax(args)
    .done((msg) => {
        // connect to your server
        const socket = io('http://localhost:3000', {
            transports: ['websocket']
        });

        // manager events
        //_________________________________________________________________________________________________
        socket.io.on('connect_error', (err) => {
            console.error(`manager:connect_error ${err}`);
        });

        socket.io.on('connect_timeout', () => {
            console.error(`manager:connect_timeout`);
        });

        socket.io.on('reconnect_attempt', (attempt) => {
            console.error(`manager:reconnect_attempt ${attempt}`);
        });

        socket.io.on('reconnecting', (attempt) => {
            console.error(`manager:reconnecting ${attempt}`);
        });

        socket.io.on('reconnect_error', (err) => {
            console.error(`manager:reconnect_error ${err}`);
        });

        socket.io.on('reconnect_failed', () => {
            console.error(`manager:reconnect_failed`);
        });
        //_________________________________________________________________________________________________

        // socket events
        //_________________________________________________________________________________________________
        socket.on('connect', () => {
            console.log(`socket:connect ${socket.connected}`);
        });

        socket.on('connect_error', (err) => {
            console.error(`socket:connect_error ${err}`);
        });

        socket.on('connect_timeout', (timeout) => {
            console.error(`socket:connect_timeout ${timeout}`);
        });

        socket.on('error', (err) => {
            console.error(`socket:error ${err}`);
        });

        socket.on('disconnect', (reason) => {
            console.info(`socket:disconnect ${reason}`);
            if (reason === 'io server disconnect') {
                // the disconnection was initiated by the server, you need to reconnect manually
                socket.connect();
            }
            // else the socket will automatically try to reconnect
        });

        socket.on('reconnect', (attempt) => {
            console.error(`socket:reconnect ${attempt}`);
        });

        socket.on('reconnect_attempt', (attempt) => {
            console.error(`socket:reconnect_attempt ${attempt}`);
        });

        socket.on('reconnecting', (attempt) => {
            console.error(`socket:reconnecting ${attempt}`);
        });

        socket.on('reconnect_error', (err) => {
            console.error(`socket:reconnect_error ${err}`);
        });

        socket.on('reconnect_failed', () => {
            console.error(`socket:reconnect_failed`);
        });
        //_________________________________________________________________________________________________

        // custom events
        //_________________________________________________________________________________________________
        socket.on('hello', (message) => {
            console.info(message);

            socket.emit('hello', {foo: 'baz'});
        });
        //_________________________________________________________________________________________________

        resolve(msg);
    })
    .fail((jqXHR, msg) => {
        console.error(msg);
    });
```